# Parsing a substring using the string method find

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to to use the `string.find` method to slice out the floating point number.

I was able to determine that the `:` is at the 18th position using the following: `substr1a = substr1.find(':')`

But I  fail to extract what I need to.

```
substr1 = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475'
substr1a = substr1.find(':')
substr1b = substr1.find[substr1a,30 ]
print substr1b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 8, in <module>
    substr1b = substr1.find[substr1a,30 ]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Functions are called using round brackets: `substr1b = substr1.find(substr1a,30)`

Comment: In addition to that, maybe you want to do `prefix_ignore, substr1b = substr1.split(':')` instead of your find and substring. And choose better names for your variables ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

This error means that your're trying to treat the object as a sequence by using square brackets. That's what square brackets do: point at en element or a sub-sequence in an ordered sequence (like a string or a list).

`string.find` is a function and not an ordered sequence, but the string itself is a sequence.

```
string = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475'

#the number starts after the space character, which is next to the colon.
# here we use round brackets
substr_start = string.find(' ')

# to actually get the substring from a string we have to slice it
# for slicing we use square brackets
# [n:] means from n to the end
substring = string[substr_start:]

# Here's another way. We split the string by ':' and take the second element
# .strip() removes extra space
substring2 = string.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Comment: That did it thank you very much for you help.

Comment: @ArnoldDent if the answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the V button on the left side, under the arrows. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer